# Does ng-socket-io allow rooms/joining? If not, how do I make a specific user join a room?

Tags: node.js, angular, sockets, socket.io

I want to join a room using [`ng-socket-io`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-socket-io). I know Socket.IO [supports rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/) so it's definitely something that is possible with Socket.IO.

I basically want connected users to join a room, so I can tell them apart on the backend. Here's an example of what I do right now, which I can't really make work on the backend:

```
this.socket.emit("setRoom", room.id);
```

I then grab that on the backend:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    socket.on('setRoom', (roomId) => {
        socket.roomId = roomId;
    });
});
```

Then I basically want to do something like this, when I want to emit a new message to *that* room:

```
io.clients.forEach(client => {
    if(client.roomId === roomId) {
        client.emit("newMessage", "some message to those only");
    }
});
```

Is that even possible with `ng-socket-io`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has anything to do with ng-socket-io, all you need is on the backend.

Instead of this...

```
io.clients.forEach(client => {
    if(client.roomId === roomId) {
        client.emit("newMessage", "some message to those only");
    }
});
```

try this on the latest version of socket-io ...

```
_.forEach(io.sockets.sockets, (socket) => {
    if(socket.roomId === roomId) {
        io.to(roomId).emit("newMessage", "some message to those only");
    }
});
```